# Dynamic Programming Solution for a Variant of Coin Exchange

Tags: algorithm, recursion, dynamic-programming, coin-change

I am practicing Dynamic Programming. I am focusing on the following variant of the coin exchange problem:

Let `S = [1, 2, 6, 12, 24, 48, 60]` be a constant set of integer coin denominations. Let `n` be a positive integer amount of money attainable via coins in `S`. Consider two persons `A` and `B`. In how many different ways can I split `n` among persons `A` and `B` so that each person gets the same amount of coins (disregarding the actual amount of money each gets)?

**Example**

`n = 6` can be split into 4 different ways per person:

1. Person `A` gets {2, 2} and person `B` gets {1, 1}.
2. Person `A` gets {2, 1} and person `B` gets {2, 1}.
3. Person `A` gets {1, 1} and person `B` gets {2, 2}.
4. Person `A` gets {1, 1, 1} and person `B` gets {1, 1, 1}.

Notice that each way is non-redundant per person, i.e. we do not count both {2, 1} and {1, 2} as two different ways.

**Previous research**

I have studied at very similar DP problems, such as the coin exchange problem and the partition problem. In fact, there are questions in this site referring to almost the same problem:

- [Dynamic Programming for a variant of the coin exchange](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48422632/dynamic-programming-for-a-variant-of-the-coin-exchange) - Here, OP studies the recursion relationship, but seems confused introducing the parity constraint.
- [Coin Change :Dynamic Programming](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23557648/coin-change-dynamic-programming) - Here, OP seems to pursue the reconstruction of the solution.
- [Coin change(Dynamic programming)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45668946/coin-changedynamic-programming) - Here, OP seems to also pursue the reconstruction of the solution.
- https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/87230/dynamic-programming-for-a-variant-of-the-coin-exchange-problem - Here, OP seems to ask about a similar problem, yet parity, i.e. splitting into two persons, becomes the main issue.

I am interested mostly in the recursion relation that could help me solve this problem. Defining it will allow me to easily apply either a memoization of a tabulation approach to design an algorithm for this problem.

For example, this recursion:

```
def f(n, coins):
  if n < 0:
    return 0

  if n == 0:
    return 1

  return sum([f(n - coin, coins) for coin in coins])
```

Is tempting, yet it does not work, because when executed:

```
# => f(6, [1, 2, 6]) # 14
```

Here's an example of a run for `S' = {1, 2, 6}` and `n = 6`, in order to help me clarify the pattern (there might be errors):

[image: Example for S' = {1, 2, 6} and n = 6]

Comment: So you're basically looking for the number of partitions with an even number of parts?

Comment: @m69: Am I? I am not sure I am looking for partitions, before the two sets I am looking for may contain the same elements, thus violating the definition of partitioning a set. For example, for S = {1, 2, 6}, A valid solution is S1 = {1,1,1} and S2 = {1,1,1}. Their intersection is not empty.

Comment: You're right, I misread the question.

Comment: Bottom-up implementation added. This produces an answer for `f(500, [1, 2, 6, 12, 24, 48, 60])` in about 2 seconds.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is what you can try:

Let `C(n, k, S)` be the number of distinct representations of an amount `n` using some `k` coins from `S`.

Then `C(n, k, S) = sum(C(n - s_i, k - 1, S[i:]))` The summation is for every `s_i` from `S`. `S[i:]` means all the elements from `S` starting from `i`-th element to the end - we need this to prevent repeated combinations.

The initial conditions are `C(0, 0, _) = 1` and `C(n, k, _) = 0` if `n < 0` or `k < 0` or `n > 0` and `k < 1` .

The number you want to calculate:

`R = sum(C(i, k, S) * C(n - i, k, S))` for `i = 1..n-1`, `k = 1..min(i, n-i)/Smin` where `Smin` - the smallest coin denomination from `S`.

The value `min(i, n-i)/Smin` represents the maximum number of coins that is possible when partitioning the given sum. For example if the sum `n = 20` and `i = 8` (1st person gets $8, 2nd gets $12) and the minimum coin denomination is $2, the maximum possible number of coins is `8/2 = 4`. You can't get $8 with `>4` coins.

Comment: I tried to implement your idea here: https://repl.it/@gl_dbrqn/CloseKindlyMemoryallocator but I'm getting 3 for `f(6, [1, 2, 6])`, where the answer should be 4; and 1 for `f(10, [1, 2, 6])`, where the answer should be 11. The code is very straightforward Python. Could you please take a look and maybe help me see a mistake? (I believe the code here produces correct results for comparison: https://repl.it/@gl_dbrqn/SlipperyStylishBases)

Comment: @גלעדברקן you actually have found an error in my formulas, now it should be fine, I fixed it. See https://repl.it/repls/WellwornGeneralMetrics

Comment: Cool. But this doesn't seem to help much. Your code (https://repl.it/@gl_dbrqn/WelltodoBigheartedRar) takes about 8-9 seconds for `n = 100`, whereas mine takes about 0.07-0.1 seconds (https://repl.it/@gl_dbrqn/RubberyIllRouter). Could you possibly optimize it further?

Comment: @גלעדברקן but that code just proves that the formula works, it does no memoization/DP at all. If you’re interested in comparing the speed feel free to improve it :) Anyway, since your solution is quite fast you can add another answer.

Comment: Added a bottom-up implementation crediting your answer. Great work!

Comment: As I follow this amazing answer to learn from it, I can't help but notice that `k = 1..min(i, n-i)/min(s)` is better written, since `k = 1..min(i, n-i)/min(s_i)` could be misinterpreted as "take the minimum of all the coins in `S` up to the `i`th coin", which I actually tried first!

Comment: @Eduardo yep, that was a bit misleading, fixed it

Comment: @algrid, could you elaborate a little bit more about the quantity `min(i, n-i)/min(s)`? ^^

Answer (score 1):

Here is a table implementation and a little elaboration on [algrid's beautiful answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50242120/2034787). This produces an answer for `f(500, [1, 2, 6, 12, 24, 48, 60])` in about 2 seconds.

The simple declaration of `C(n, k, S) = sum(C(n - s_i, k - 1, S[i:]))` means adding all the ways to get to the current sum, `n` using `k` coins. Then if we split `n` into all ways it can be partitioned in two, we can just add all the ways each of those parts can be made from the same number, `k`, of coins.

The beauty of fixing the subset of coins we choose from to a diminishing list means that any arbitrary combination of coins will only be counted once - it will be counted in the calculation where the leftmost coin in the combination is the first coin in our diminishing subset (assuming we order them in the same way). For example, the arbitrary subset `[6, 24, 48]`, taken from `[1, 2, 6, 12, 24, 48, 60]`, would only be counted in the summation for the subset `[6, 12, 24, 48, 60]` since the next subset, `[12, 24, 48, 60]` would not include `6` and the previous subset `[2, 6, 12, 24, 48, 60]` has at least one `2` coin.

Python code (see it [here](https://repl.it/@gl_dbrqn/SlatebluePastProprietarysoftware); confirm [here](https://repl.it/@gl_dbrqn/WelltodoBigheartedRar-2)):

```py
import time

def f(n, coins):
  t0 = time.time()

  min_coins = min(coins)

  m = [[[0] * len(coins) for k in xrange(n / min_coins + 1)] for _n in xrange(n + 1)]

  # Initialize base case
  for i in xrange(len(coins)):
    m[0][0][i] = 1

  for i in xrange(len(coins)):
    for _i in xrange(i + 1):
      for _n in xrange(coins[_i], n + 1):
        for k in xrange(1, _n / min_coins + 1):
          m[_n][k][i] += m[_n - coins[_i]][k - 1][_i]

  result = 0

  for a in xrange(1, n + 1):
    b = n - a

    for k in xrange(1, n / min_coins + 1):
      result = result + m[a][k][len(coins) - 1] * m[b][k][len(coins) - 1]

  total_time = time.time() - t0

  return (result, total_time)

print f(500, [1, 2, 6, 12, 24, 48, 60])
```